# How to print my public IP address in the terminal using wget

Tags: bash, command, ip, public

I want to print my public IP address in the terminal. I found a webpage called `http://ipecho.net/plain`, it only displays the IP address.

What is the simplest way to print it to my bash?

Is it something close to `wget http://ipecho.net/plain | cat plain` or `echo $(wget http://ipecho.net/plain)`? (none of the above mentioned commands prints the expected output)

Thanks,
Polb

Answer (score 3):

With wget, you have to tell it not to show the progress bars, and to send output to stdout instead of a file:

```
wget -q -O- http://ipecho.net/plain
```

Answer (score 1):

use **wget**:

```bash
wget -q -O- https://ipecho.io/plain
```

use **curl**:

```bash
curl https://ipecho.io/plain
```

if you want **JSON** format:

```bash
curl https://ipecho.io/json
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be;

```
wget -qO- ipaddress.ai
```

Answer (score 0):

if in addition you want to process/store the public ip, it is

```
pubIP=`wget -q -O- http://ipecho.net/plain`
# e.g.
echo $pubIP > myPubIp.txt
```

Comment: Don't use backticks: https://www.shellcheck.net/wiki/SC2006 -- `pubIP=$(...)`

Comment: @glenn jackman both works for me in this case, your reference might support an example, where it would not.